# VBScript get contents of html table text input field

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vbscript

I have this working in javascript, but employer wants it in VBScript.  I have a series of text inputs inside cells of a table.  The table was dynamically created using javascript like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var row = table.insertRow(-1);  // Insert row at end of table
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

Then elsewhere in VBScript I do this:

```
dim table 
set table = document.getElementById( tableID )
dim value1, value2
value1 = table.rows(1).cells(0).innerText
value2 = table.rows(1).cells(0).childNodes.innerText  ' This errors
```

And it does not return anything, which is strange because in javascript this works fine:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var value = table.rows[1].cells[0].childNodes[0].value;
```

I know I'm probably making a simple mistake, but I've searched for hours and can't find how to access a dynamically created text input in a table cell.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.childNodes(0)`? And why does your employer want vbscript?!

Comment: .childNodes(0) and .childNodes(0).innerText both throw an error expecting a function.  They need VBScript for some of their clients using older legacy systems.  I know it's a pain.

Comment: what is the precise error you are getting?

Comment: the .childNodes.innerText error is "Object doesn't support this property or method".  The .childNodes(0) and .childNodes(0).innerText error is "Function Expected"

Comment: My vbscript is really rusty, but try .childNodes.Item(0) or .children(0)... Why not .firstChild. Who knows how much of the DOM  API is implemented in vbscript...

Comment: table.rows(1).cells(0).childNodes.item(0).value  did the trick!  Thanks for the help @bfavaretto !